# How to layout a Silverlight app?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, layout, silverlight-3.0

I am brand new to Silverlight.  Just downloaded and installed it (the SDK and the controls toolkit), went through a few tutorial and getting my head around XAML.

I want to build a fairly simple app with 3 panes.  It should look similar to the image below.
[alt text http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/panels.jpg](http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/panels.jpg)

Panel 1 will have a TreeView.  Whenever the user clicks on a node, something else will load into panel 2.  Panel 3 will just be the logo, version info, etc...

My question is what controls should I use to build a layout like this?

Answer (score 2):

For this layout, I'd use a Grid, two cells wide and two cells high.  You can set the title cell over the top to span the two columns.  You'll probably want a StackPanel with vertical orientation in Panel 3 for your textual layout.

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight Tutorial Part 2: Using Layout Management](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-2-using-layout-management.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should take some time out to research the [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) guidelines.  This should help you get up and running with such an application layout fairly quickly.